# Exporting a BIP32 public key (in Base64)

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

I am using [this](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip32) BIP32 implementation to derive keys. How can I export the derived public keys in Base64?

```
var node = bip32js.bip32.fromBase58('<some private key>');
var child = node.derivePath('m/0/0');
var publicKey = child.publicKey(); // This gets the public key for the child
console.log(btoa(publicKey)) // This gives an error since the returned public key is not a string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[junderw on Github](https://github.com/junderw) answered this:

> publicKey is a Buffer.
>
> publicKey.toString('hex') will turn it into a hex string.

Similarly, for Base64, 'base64' can be used.